# All floats with two decimal places between two numbers (range) in R

Tags: r, precision

I was looking for the answer, but I didn't find any solution for R.
It's easy to get numbers all numbers in range, e.g. between 1 and 10:

```
> 1:10
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

But what if I'm looking for something like this:

```
1.00, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, ... , 9.98, 9.99, 10.00
```

So all floats with two decimal places. Of course it may be 3 or 4 places. Do you know some easy solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `seq` function and set the by argument to be the difference you want between numbers.  For the example you listed, try

```r
seq(1, 10, 0.01)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `seq` and specify the `by` as 0.01:

```
seq(1, 10, by=0.01)
[1]  1.00  1.01  1.02  1.03  1.04  1.05  1.06 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `seq(1, 10, by=0.01)`, you can generate all the integers from `100` to `1000` with the `colon` operator, and divide all of them with `100`:

```r
> 100:1000 / 100
  [1]  1.00  1.01  1.02  1.03  1.04  1.05  1.06  1.07  1.08  1.09  1.10  1.11
...
[901] 10.00
```